# MySQL query went wrong

Tags: php, mysql

can you say me where are i am making mistakes in this simple query

```
 $q = "UPDATE users SET ".$aItemSlot." = '$seton' WHERE username='$us'"; 
    $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q); 
   $q = "UPDATE items SET item_position='3' WHERE it_id='$seton'"; 
   $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
```

error-

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> ```
> near ''$aItemSlot' = '$seton' WHERE username='$us'' at line 1
> ```

Here is my source

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$us'";
$r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $r);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
       $aHelmet_Slot  = $row['helmet_slot'];
       $aShield_Slot  = $row['shield_slot'];
       $aWeapon_Slot  = $row['weapon_slot'];
       $aGloves_Slot  = $row['g1loves_slot'];
       $aShoes_Slot  = $row['shoes_slot'];
       $aArmor_Slot  = $row['armor_slot'];
       $aEar_Slot  = $row['ear_slot'];
       $aBelt_Slot  = $row['belt_slot'];
       $aRing1_Slot  = $row['ring1_slot'];
       $aRing2_Slot  = $row['ring2_slot'];
       $aRing3_Slot  = $row['ring3_slot'];
       $aRing4_Slot  = $row['ring4_slot'];
       $aCharLevel  = $row['char_lvl'];


    if ($aItemSlot == 'ring_slot'){
    if($aCharLevel >= $aItem_Level){
        $NotEmpty = false; 
        if ($aRing1_Slot == 0){
            $q = "UPDATE users SET ring1_slot='$seton' WHERE username='$us'";
            $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
            $NotEmpty = true;
        }
        if (($aRing2_Slot == 0) && (!$NotEmpty)){
            $q = "UPDATE users SET ring2_slot='$seton' WHERE username='$us'";
            $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
            $NotEmpty = true;
        }
        if (($aRing3_Slot == 0) && (!$NotEmpty)){
            $q = "UPDATE users SET ring3_slot='$seton' WHERE username='$us'";
            $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
            $NotEmpty = true;
        }
        if(($aRing4_Slot == 0) && (!$NotEmpty)){
            $q = "UPDATE users SET ring4_slot='$seton' WHERE username='$us'";
            $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
            $NotEmpty = true;
        }
        if(!$NotEmpty){
            $q = "UPDATE items SET item_position='2' WHERE it_id='$aRing1_Slot'";
            $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
            $q = "UPDATE users SET ring1_slot='$seton' WHERE username='$us'";
            $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
            $NotEmpty = true;
        }
        $q = "UPDATE items SET item_position='3' WHERE it_id='$seton'";
        $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    }
}
else 
{
    if ($aCharLevel >= $aItem_Level){
        $link_slot_var = "a" .$aItemSlot;
        $aSlotItemID = $$link_slot_var;
        if($aSlotItemID <> 0){
            $q = "UPDATE items SET item_position='2' WHERE it_id='$aSlotItemID'";
            $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
        }
        $q = "UPDATE users SET '$aItemSlot' = '.$seton.' WHERE username='$us'; // it fails there 
        $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
        $q = "UPDATE items SET item_position='3' WHERE it_id='$seton'";
        $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    }
}
```

Comment: Assignment operator.

Comment: Also your quotes are wrong.

Comment: I think that you need to read about both - PHP and MYSQL syntax!

Comment: Post your original query with PHP code

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Comment: this is what i am doing actually as you mensiod above already i hope

Comment: @Jas - Apologies, read the question too quickly ;)

Comment: @Ocracoke - any suggestions ?)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use a table name as variable?

```
{$aItemSlot}
```

In general it should be like this:

```
$mysqli->query("Update users 
set aItemSlot = '$seton'
where username = $us
") ;
```

Also, try to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

**UPDATE**
Make update of the row which related to this table:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

> UPDATE statement updates columns of existing rows in the named table
> with new values. The SET clause indicates which columns to modify and
> the values they should be given. Each value can be given as an
> expression, or the keyword DEFAULT to set a column explicitly to its
> default value. The WHERE clause, if given, specifies the conditions
> that identify which rows to update. With no WHERE clause, all rows are
> updated. If the ORDER BY clause is specified, the rows are updated in
> the order that is specified. The LIMIT clause places a limit on the
> number of rows that can be updated.

You can also perform UPDATE operations covering multiple tables.

```
UPDATE items,month SET items.price=month.price
WHERE items.id=month.id;
```

**UPDATE2**
You need to check/update each row.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE table SET col1 = ?, col2 = ?, col3 = ? WHERE id = ? ")
$stmt->bind_param('sssi', $var1, $var2, $var3, $id);
```

This shows what [you need to do](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: let me try, a minute please

Comment: i am doing in this way due to that item_slot_name not in the table users, it is in another table

Comment: @mally - give me a moment i will try

Comment: not working as well, tables are referencing among each other, other queryes working correctly

Comment: Provide me with a:
show create table users;
show create table items;

Comment: you have a big table, check UPDATE2 of the post

Answer (score 1):

There Should not be a **$** symbol before the mysql database field name it should be something like this

```
UPDATE users SET aItemSlot = '".$seton."' WHERE username='".$us."'
```

Modify your query in the above format and try to execute

Comment: this because aItemSlot row is not exists in the table users, it is located to other table

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'aItemSlot' in 'field list'

Comment: If the field doesnnot exists in the same table and it is in some other table you need to join the tables and try to fetch the exact value

Comment: with out having "aItemSlot" field in the table how can you update that field

Comment: thats why i am referencing this var to that table

Answer (score 0):

You missed assignment operator :

```
UPDATE users SET " . $aItemSlot . " = '" . $seton . "' WHERE username='$us'";
```

Comment: Same error, #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '" . $aItemSlot . " = '" . $seton . "' WHERE username='$us'' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like this:

```
"UPDATE users SET " . $aItemSlot . "='$seton' WHERE username='$us'";
                                    ^ assignment operator
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid syntax.. how ever you have to be sure that those params are VALID before making the query...

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET {$aItemSlot} = '{$seton}' WHERE username = '{$us}'";
```

Comment: Either $aItemSlot is wrong table field name or the other 2 values are not escaped ! 
This syntax is correct..

Comment: thanks a lot, i will take a look in to my table again

Comment: $aItemslot, first i am retreiving this from my table as $aItemSlot = $row['item_slot_name'] then i am trying to make some operations on it

Comment: $aItemSlot should be the name of your field inside the table.. 
item_slot_name perhaps.. not a value taken from the DB

Comment: this means that first i have to populate my table with some data ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will surely work

```
 $q = "UPDATE users SET ".$aItemSlot." = " . $seton . " WHERE username= " . $us;
```

Comment: or can i give my $aItemSlot source ?

Comment: Have you tried printing $aItemSlot, what value it has??

Comment: yeah i am printing the value via function DrawItem, weapon is displaying in my inventory but not wearing it on, php error is Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in

Comment: Have you tried passing the column name in place of $aItemSlot, please try it and check if you get an error then

Comment: yeah of cource first i am fetching the row than using it

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make some slight adjustments.

#### PHP/SQL

```
$q = "UPDATE users SET aItemSlot = '".$seton."' WHERE username='".$us."'";

// Or if $aItemSlot actually is a variable
$q = "UPDATE users SET '".$aItemSlot."'='".$seton."' WHERE username='".$us."'";
```

Bottom note: because `$aItemSlot` starts with an 'a' I am wondering if this is an array. In that case your script will fail saying that the array to string conversion has failed. If this is the case, check what value `$aItemSlot` holds using `var_dump()`.